# Stripe TypeError: Cannot read property 'payment_intent' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, sails.js

I'm integrating the payment methods to the app with Stripe and Paypal and now working on Stripe integration.

The backend is Node, Sails.js, and the frontend is React.js.

I followed the guide they provided but and tested the payment processing using testing card.

But I got the error, which says **TypeError: Cannot read property 'payment_intent' of undefined**.

Here is my code.

```
- Frontend
this.props.stripe.createPaymentMethod({
    type: 'card',
    card: cardElement,
}).then(({paymentMethod}) => {
// API call
})


- Backend
subscribe = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
     customer: customerId,
     items: [
        {price: plan.stripe.stripeId},
     ],
     expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent']
});
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to verify if `latest_invoice` is available before you index for `payment_intent`?

Comment: Is there more code that you've left out? You don't appear to be accessing `payment_intent` so it is unclear where this error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you don't have to create the PaymentIntent per subscrition.

Here is what Stripe API docs says about paymentIntent.

> A PaymentIntent guides you through the process of collecting a payment from your customer. We recommend that you create exactly one PaymentIntent for each order or customer session in your system. You can reference the PaymentIntent later to see the history of payment attempts for a particular session.

So they recommend to create the paymentIntent per transaction and in subscription case, the payment is proceed in background automatically and paymentIntent is also generated in my experience.

But on the other hand in checkout option, you need to create the paymentIntent first before proceeding the payment.

I think you code was not wrong but I think you didn't follow the correct guide from **Stripe** or used wrong credit card.

Please refer this link:
[Stripe API Payment_intents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents)